# Declare function as a parameter in Typings Declaration

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, typescript-typings

In my `globals.d.ts` I export multiple functions whose parameters are also functions. An example can be viewed below:

```
/**
 * Does something
 * @param {function(string): void} bar - a parameter
 * @returns {void}
 */
export function foo(bar: function(string): void): void;
```

ESLint is showing multiple errors stating that:`JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments.`. I tried fixing this error by removing the types from the function and only stating them in the comments, but then the type of the parameter becomes `any (*)`. I also tried adding the `"valid-jsdoc": "off"` rule in the `.eslintrc.json`file, with no success. Is there a way to remove the warning without losing the type of the parameter?

Comment: why not returning a promise resolved with the string ?

Comment: @Kulvar This is just a simplified example of what my function declarations look like, most if not all of them do in fact return something else and I would not want to return an object that contains both the promise and the actual result, as it complicated things. Furthermore, that solution will not solve the problem regarding eslint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify parameter type as `function(string): void`. It's just wrong syntax to define function types in TypeScript.
Instead of:
`export function foo(bar: function(string): void): void;`
do:
`export function foo(bar: (arg: string) => void): void;`